# Using a copy of a ViewController in the same app with additional functionalities

Tags: ios, swift, algorithm, viewcontroller

I've downloaded a calendar app's source code form Github. The app has a  CalendarViewController that contains a child UIView (called calendarView).

This has multiple classes (CalendarDayView, CalendarMonthView etc. etc. and the protocols are also written for some of the classes)

I have integrated this calendar app into my custom iPhone app, that has a TableViewController. The rest of the information is given in the image.

**Notes:**

1. Programming language = Swift.
2. I'm a complete novice, so please try to be elaborative.
3. I don't know if the given information will be enough to get the perfect answer (as I understand that the answer to this type of question depends on how the CalendarApp has been programmed).
4. Please see the attached file to understand the info.

Thanks in advance.
[image: The description of the problem]

Comment: A `UIViewController` instance may only appear once in the navigation stack. You are free to instantiate a second instance of the same class and provide additional configuration such that it behaves differently. This completely depends on the actual `UIViewController` subclass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is totally fine. Just ensure that your have two instances of `CalendarViewController`.

For example, when you instantiate your navigation controller you have:

```
let calendar1 = CalendarViewController()
let navC = UINavigationController(rootViewController:calendar1)
```

And then when a button is clicked in your `TableViewController`:

```
let calendar2 = CalendarViewController()
self.navigationController.pushViewController(calendar2,animated:true)
```

Because you are making two initialisations, each `CalendarViewController` will be a completely separate object and setting some variables on one of them will not result in that variable being updated in the second one.

Comment: thanks for the answer. And I'm sorry for the late response but I could not check earlier.

After applying your method, 
The code compiles but after the app is run and I click on the row of the tableView (from which I want to access the calendar2) I get an error: "Unexpectedly found nil while wrapping an optional value" and points to the place in the CalendarViewController() class to the following statement:     calendarView.layer.borderWidth = 1
// Where calendarView is another class.

Comment: It means that your calendarCiew is an IBOutlet. In this case you need to use initWithNibName in order to load xib of your CalendarViewController

Comment: Continued from the previous comment:..... There are some other properties of the calendarView also initiated like calendarView.layer.borderWidth. when I put the ? mark after calendarView in the code like calendarView?.layer.borderwidth = 1 (and in all other statements of the similar look, the error disappears but I get a black screen when I click on the row of the tableView (to load the new instance of the CalendarViewController()).

Comment: Yup, exactly, it's an IBOutlet.

Comment: Do you use storyboards?

Comment: Yup, previously before applying your method, I duplicated the classes as well as the storyboard of the CalendarViewController as well.

Comment: If you are using storyboards then simply create a new scene with CalendarViewController. This will behave like a new instance. Think of it as if you were creating a scene with totally different class.

Comment: Do I need to duplicate the CalendarViewController in storyboard and attach it with the relevant original CalendarViewController class?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You can have as many scenes as you wish all being CalendarViewController. And each scene will behave like a totally new instance isolated from any other :)

Comment: Sorry, but I've already told I'm complete like a novice here. I've copied the CalendarViewController from the storyboard and pasted it somewhere else. I've not connected it with the storyboard segue to the row form the tableViewController. I get the same error I was getting before. Even connecting it with a storyboard segue makes no difference.

Comment: Do not copy it outside of your storyboard. Just create a new scene in the storyboard with CalendarViewController

Comment: By somewhere else I meant to say within the storyboard but at another place. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I've updated the question and added the snapshot of what I've done in the storyboard and what error I'm getting from it. Could you please view and suggest me solution?

Comment: It all depends on what functionality you need. If all you want is to allow your CalendarViewController to be non-clickable you can simply create a boolean variable called 'clickable' which defaults to true. In the first instance you do not have to modify it. When you instantiate the second instance in preperForSegue method set this to false. Then modify your code so that cells/other elements set userInteractionEnabled (or simply enabled) to the value of clickable.

Comment: I'm still not able to recover from that error I was getting from your instructions.

Comment: From what you have described you do not have any errors. You just want your view controller to have additional functionality (to tell it that it should not be clickable). So you need to add properties/methods which will allow you to do this. Then in your 3rd controller in prepareForSegue method you can tell your 4th view controller that it should be unclickable and also tell it which dates it needs to highlight.